# Fetch Max & Min number in a VBA collection

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a **VBA collection** named as Num_Key (Num_Key as New Collection) where it will store unique numbers in it.

Is there any way to fetch the **minimum** and **maximum** numbers from **Num_Key** VBA collection without loop?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Convert the collection to array
2. Use `WorksheetFunction.Max` or `WorksheetFunction.Min` on the array.

Like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim myCollection As New Collection
    
    myCollection.Add 1
    myCollection.Add 2
    myCollection.Add 100
    myCollection.Add 50
    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Max(CollectionToArray(myCollection))

End Sub

Public Function CollectionToArray(myCol As Collection) As Variant

    Dim result  As Variant
    Dim cnt     As Long

    'Empty collection check:
    If myCol.Count < 1 Then
        CollectionToArray = 0
        Exit Function
    End If

    ReDim result(myCol.Count - 1)
    For cnt = 0 To myCol.Count - 1
        result(cnt) = myCol(cnt + 1)
    Next cnt
    CollectionToArray = result

End Function
```

Comment: 'CollectionToArray' fails for empty collections. Maybe add an 'If myCol.Count > 0 Then' for the 4 relevant lines.

Comment: And 'ELSE', 'ReDim result(0)', 'End If'. Otherwise, a count of the result would be 1.

Comment: @CodePrinz - thanks for the notes, I have updated it.

Comment: Actually, somewhere in 2021 I have found that mistake, but I have fixed it only in my GitHub repository, and not in the StackOverflow answer - https://github.com/Vitosh/VBA_personal/commit/8754002bec3fbb3147680d79a034d6e61889fcea